# My code instead of Go to start a new line, sends a message

Tags: python

I can’t get the text out in one message.

```
keyboard.write("-------------------------------\n" + "1) " + name + " (-)\n" + "2) " + rules + " / " + times + "\n" + "3) by Fagi_Zak\n" + "4) " + str(Total) + "-------------------------------")
```

The full code, opens Discord, clicks on "write to #chat" and after each "" sends a message, although should just start a new line.
full code:

```
import os
import pyautogui
import win32api
import time
import mouseinfo
import win32api, win32con
import keyboard

name = (input("Ник игрока? "))
rules = (input("Номер правила? "))
times = (input("Время наказания? "))
Total_punishment = int(input( "Введите номер вашего ПОСЛЕДНЕГО наказания: "))
one = int(1)
Total = Total_punishment + one

print("-------------------------------")
print("1) " + name + " (-)")
print("2) " + rules + " / " + times)
print("3) by Fagi_Zak")
print("4) " + str(Total))
print("-----------------------------------")

os.startfile(r'C:\Users\Romanlll333\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9008\Discord.exe')
time.sleep(1.5)
pyautogui.click(685, 872)

keyboard.write("-------------------------------\n" + "1) " + name + " (-)\n" + "2) " + rules + " / " + times + "\n" + "3) by Fagi_Zak\n" + "4) " + str(Total) + "-------------------------------")

keyboard.send("enter")

while Total<35:
    name = (input("Ник игрока? "))
    rules = (input("Номер правила? "))
    times = (input("Время наказания? "))
    Total_punishment = int(input("Введите номер вашего ПОСЛЕДНЕГО наказания: "))
    one = int(1)
    Total = Total_punishment + one

    print("-------------------------------")
    print("1) " + name + " (-)")
    print("2) " + rules + " / " + times)
    print("3) by Fagi_Zak")
    print("4) " + str(Total))
    print("-----------------------------------")

    os.startfile(r'C:\Users\Romanlll333\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9008\Discord.exe')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    pyautogui.click(685, 872)

    keyboard.write("-------------------------------\n" + "1) " + name + " (-)\n" + "2) " + rules + " / " + times + "\n" + "3) by Fagi_Zak\n" + "4) " + str(Total) + "-------------------------------")

    keyboard.send("enter")

if Total >= 35:
    print("Please, уйди. Ты норму уже сделал.")
    input("P.s Нажми ENTER")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think keyboard.write() + Discord turns \n into some enter press. I only got it solved like this:

```
import keyboard
text = "asdas\ndasd"

keyboard.press("shift")
keyboard.write(text)
keyboard.release("shift")
```